# series sum of sigmoid functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

This is apparently true (from a paper on Restricted Boltzmann Machines):

$${\sum}_{i=1}^{\infty}1/(1+e^{i-(x+0.5)})\approx \ln(1+e^x)$$

(according to the author an "extremely close" approximation)  If you just do an integral, you get:

$${\int}^{\infty}_1dy/(1+e^{y-(x+0.5)})=(y-\ln(1+e^ye^{-(x+0.5)})){\vert}^{\infty}_1=-\ln(e^{-y}+e^{-(x+0.5)}){\vert}^{\infty}_1=\ln(1+e^{x-0.5})$$

I also tried the expansion (with a resulting double sum):  $$1/(1+x)={\sum}_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^jx^j$$I'm missing a trick.
Anyone have any clue how to derive this?  Thank you much.

Comment: why not lower limit 0 for integral instead of 1?

Comment: That changes the question.  The lower limit is 1.

Comment: no it doesn't. It only changes the integral approximation of the sum.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{-x+y-\frac{1}{2}}+1} \, dy=\ln(1+e^x)$$

Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate the post, however I was hoping for something a bit more formal.  Thank you.